# Generic method to remove duplicate from any collection of data

Tags: java

I have to remove duplicate rows from random collections of data.

The data is retrieved from the database as a JSONArray object by an api and can come any number/type of columns.

For example while in one case it could be like:

```
TimeStamp              Id   Value   Person
---------             ----  -----   ------
01-01-2018 14:22:16    12    0.3     Mac
01-01-2018 14:32:16    11    0.1     Arya
01-01-2018 14:32:16     2    0.8     Stephen
01-01-2018 14:32:16    11    0.1     Arya
```

In another case it might be something like:

```
Department     Floor    Budget
---------      -----   --------
  Sales         26      100000
 Finance        25      200000 
 Finance        25      200000
Production       1      9000000
```

I need to write a generic method that can remove duplicate from any such collection.

Fornunately,in **most** cases, the duplicate rows can be identified by 2 or 3 columns. (For example, in the first example set, if `TimeStamp` and `Id` are same, the row can be considered a duplicate)

Right now , I can think of only the naive way of doing this:

Write a method, that

1. Takes the input data and the list of columns that identifies a duplicate row as arguments
2. For each row creates a string that is concat of the unique row identifier columns
3. Keeps adding the above string to a set.
4. For any row, if the above string is already in the set(duplicate row), continue, else add the row to the output array.

Basically, write a method like :

```
public JSONArray removeDuplicateRows(JSONArray input,List<String> dupCriteriaColumns){

    JSONArray opAray = new JSONArray();
    HashSet<String>  uniqueRows = new HashSet<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        StringBuffer uniqueColString = new StringBuffer();
        JSONObject currRow = input.getJSONObject(i); 

        for (String column : dupCriteriaColumns){
            uniqueColString.add(currRow.getString(column));                         
        }

        if(uniqueRows.contains(uniqueColString)){
            // Duplicate row
            continue;
        }else{
            opAray.addJSONObject(currRow);
            uniqueRows.add(uniqueColString);
        }       

    }
    return opAray;

}
```

Of course if  the number of "unique row identifier columns" are too many, I will end up with large String objects and this solution will suck.

EDIT 1:
I would prefer not to create POJO for each data set, because type of data sets are too many,their structure changes frequently, and new types get added/removed very often.

**Can anyone suggest me a better idea/logic?**

Comment: Create POJOs for each possible result, implement `hashcode` and `equals`. Then implement a proper method to remove duplicates if you don't want to use a `Set`

Answer (score 4):

I would go through my entities and add proper equals() and hashCode() logic (based on the fields i want to be unique).

Then when retrieving the entities, i would just retrieve them in a set.

What that will do is it will effectively remove the duplicates in the set as the set uses equals and hashCode to keep unique objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the data retrieval, then I suggest to remove duplicates at DB level.

If not, I suggest to write specific methods for each type of data that you have, i.e. transform JSONArray to a specific type, and handle the duplicates there.